# Where can I find slides or videos from Devcon2 in Shanghai?

Tags: devcon

Where I can find slides, videos, etc. from Devcon2?

For now I only found this article: https://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/devcon-day2-sees-crowd-erupt-enthusiastic-applause/

Comment: I believe the slides are already available - videos will take 1-2 weeks from date, also because they're adding Chinese subtitles from what I understood.

Answer (score 8):

The official site for the agenda, slides and videos can be found at the [Ethereum Foundation Devcon2](https://ethereumfoundation.org/devcon/?page_id=14) page.

An unofficial single-page agenda with slides, videos and other links can be found at [Ethereum Devcon2 Conference In Shanghai - Unofficial Single-Page Agenda With Slides, Videos And Links](https://www.bokconsulting.com.au/blog/ethereum-devcon2-conference-in-shanghai/).

A few videos have been added so far in both links, the rest will be added when they become available.

If you really want to watch the videos now, have Adobe Flash installed and can wade through advertisements, the unedited videos are available from [here](http://list.youku.com/albumlist/show?id=28368456&ascending=1&page=1). Some people have complained about the sound quality as well.

Answer (score 6):

The Devcon 2 is held in Shanghai and for this year the Foundation hired a professional team to record all talks from any angle imaginable.

This and the reason that the internet is supposed not to be the best in the world, makes it currently impossible to have any live streams or video recordings available.

However, checkout some leaked videos uploaded by @Thibaut here: https://www.periscope.tv/vanderkriek

Also, maybe check back next week for the official recordings on the Ethereum youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/ethereumproject

Answer (score 4):

The Devcone ended on 21-09 so the videos and slides will be available later. I share with you this presentation about Geth by Péter Szilágyi

https://ethereum.karalabe.com/talks/2016-devcon.html#1

*update* the slide are available and videos available at : https://ethereumfoundation.org/devcon/?page_id=14

Answer (score 2):

Officially there are 3 videos released until now - you can find them here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/56wtmq/devcon2_slides_released/

Answer (score -1):

Link to the slides can be found here:

http://upyun-assets.ethfans.org/uploads/doc/file/57389fef0d4a4a86a17bd90f5837b03e.pdf?_upd=Ethereum_in_40_Minutes.pdf