# Where can I find slides or videos from Devcon3?

Tags: devcon

I noticed some good feedback from [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8788/where-can-i-find-slides-or-videos-from-devcon2-in-shanghai) previous discussion, so I decide to reask :)

- [Day 1 Streaming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yo9o5nDTAAQ)
- [Day 2 Streaming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMs0wAFIu7I)
- [Evolution of Smart Contract Security in the Ethereum Ecosystem](https://blog.zeppelinos.org/evolution-of-smart-contract-security-in-the-ethereum-ecosystem/)